# Фильтрация по нескольким столбцам, по нескольким значениям

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, фильтры

Подскажите, как работает логика отбора строк.

Код:

```
portfel.loc[(portfel['Тип'] == ('КК' and 'ОВ')) &
           (portfel['Номер'] == ('279' and '931' and '2667')) &
           (portfel['суммы'] == 'RUR') &
           (portfel['суммы2'] == 'RUR')]['Номер'].sample(5)
```

Проблема в том, что выводит только номера с записью 2667, вместо всех 3-х.

Поэтому вопрос, как мне передать для всех столбцов много условий сразу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> почему приведенное в вопросе выражение работает не так как задумывалось?

В Python конструкции `"str1" and "str2" and "str3"` выполняется следующим образом (слева направо):

1. проверяется первая строка - `bool("str1")` - любая *непустая* строка при проверке будет соответсвовать истинному значению (`True`)
2. если первая часть вернула `True` то проверка идет дальше и проверяется следующая строка
3. при первом попавшемся выражении `False` проверка обрывается и возвращается строка, на которой проверка вернула `False`
4. елси все строки являются непустыми (при проверке возвращают `True`), то вернется последняя строка

Примеры:

```
In [32]: ('279' and '931' and '2667')
Out[32]: '2667'

In [33]: ('279' and '' and '2667')
Out[33]: ''
```

Таким образом команда:

```
portfel['Номер'] == ('279' and '931' and '2667'))
```

эквивалентна команде:

```
portfel['Номер'] == '2667'
```

---

воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.query("...")](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)
 - имена столбцов, содержащие пробелы или символы не латинского алфавита необходимо заключить в обратные кавычки (`backtick quoted`):

```
qry = "`Тип` in ['KK','OB'] and `Номер` in ['279','931','2667'] \
       and `суммы` == 'RUR' and `суммы2` == 'RUR'"
res = portfel.query(qry)
```

или так:

```
res = portfel.loc[
    (portfel['Тип'].isin(['KK','OB']))
  & (portfel['Номер'].isin(['279','931','2667'])) 
  & (portfel['суммы'] == 'RUR') 
  & (portfel['суммы2'] == 'RUR')
]
```

---

На будущее рекомендую всегда использовать только буквы латинского алфавита для имён столбцов - это позволит использовать имена столбцов без необходимости заключать их в обратные кавычки:

```
qry = "Type in ['КК','ОВ'] and Number in ['279','931','2667'] \
       and Sum == 'RUR' and Sum2 == 'RUR'"
res = portfel.query(qry)
```